# Selecting part of text from sql database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a nvarchar field in sql database .. for example I have 4000 character in this field but I want to select only 200 first character and display in a label .

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Left(YourColumn, 200) as 'First200'
From dbo.YourTable
```

Or

```
Select SubString(YourColumn, 1, 200) as 'First200'
From dbo.YourTable
```

Information on [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

In the underlying query:

```
 SELECT 
   LEFT(fld, 200) 
 FROM T ...
```